# Mongoose: Array attribute inside a collection is returned empty by Model.find() even though it has data in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to create a test query for one of my databases using Mongoose. For this, I have created some data in a JSON file and have imported it into MongoDB. Here's the data:

```
{
    "name": "SSS",
    "discordid": "61231237",
    "prefix": "!",
    "servers": [
        {
            "name": "DMG TTT",
            "type": "garrysmod",
            "host": "66.151.244.2",
            "vchannelid": "616413849679036530",
            "tchannelid": "616414488916393984"
        },
        {
            "name": "DMG Potpourri",
            "type": "garrysmod",
            "host": "192.223.27.68",
            "vchannelid": "616415352271667232",
            "tchannelid": "616415277713981441"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the servers attribute is an array that has 2 objects inside it. However, when I query the database using Mongoose using this code:

```js
Guild.find({ name: "SSS" }).exec((err, data) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) })
```

The following is returned in console:

```
[{"servers":[],"_id":"5d675d80dd57df7e7d88e491","name":"SSS","discordid":"61231237","prefix":"!"}]
```

Notice that the servers array is returned as empty, even though it has data inside of it. Looking through some solutions, it was suggested that I try JSON.stringify, but it made no difference with or without it. Why does this happen?

EDIT: Here is the model file:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Discord Guild schema
const guildSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    discordid: String,
    prefix: String,
    servers: [{
        name: String,
        type: String,
        host: String,
        vchannelid: String,
        tchannelid: String
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Guild", guildSchema)
```

and here is the same query done thought the MongoDB CLI:

```
> db.guilds.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d675d80dd57df7e7d88e491"), "name" : "SSS", "discordid" : "61231237", "prefix" : "!", "servers" : [ { "name" : "DMG TTT", "type" : "garrysmod", "host" : "66.151.244.2", "vchannelid" : "616413849679036530", "tchannelid" : "616414488916393984" }, { "name" : "DMG Potpourri", "type" : "garrysmod", "host" : "192.223.27.68", "vchannelid" : "616415352271667232", "tchannelid" : "616415277713981441" } ] }
```

Comment: @Subburaj I edited the post to include the model file.

Comment: The data what you have provided is in DB or as you said its in JSON file?? My guess is that the data in your DB is not imported properly

Comment: @Subburaj I created JSON file to seed it, but the data has been imported into the DB.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post again to show what the mongo console query result is.

Comment: Can you try for this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: I did, still empty array returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach ,

Your guildModel ,

```
const guildSchema = Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    discordid: {type: String},
    prefix: {type: String},
    servers: [{
        name: {type: String},
        type: {type: String},
        host: {type: String},
        vchannelid: {type: String},
        tchannelid: {type: String}
    }]
})
```

First save the JSON object in your database as below- 
Your Controller File , Make sure the format is as same as below .

```
var guildModel = require('../models/guild.model');



req.body =  [{
        "name": "SSS",
        "discordid": "61231237",
        "prefix": "!",
        "servers": [
        {
            "name": "DMG TTT",
            "type": "garrysmod",
            "host": "66.151.244.2",
            "vchannelid": "616413849679036530",
            "tchannelid": "616414488916393984"
        },
        {
            "name": "DMG Potpourri",
            "type": "garrysmod",
            "host": "192.223.27.68",
            "vchannelid": "616415352271667232",
            "tchannelid": "616415277713981441"
        }
        ],

    }];
    var guild = new guildModel(req.body[0]);
    guild.save((err , userSaved)=>{
                if(err){
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    console.log("userSaved =========> " , userSaved);
                    res.json({user: userSaved});
                }
            });
```

then apply the below code to retrieve the data from the database .

```
guildModel.find({name : "SSS"})
        .exec((err , found )=>{
            if (err){
                res.send(err)
        }else{
                res.send(found);
            }
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm currently not using express. This is a discord bot project, not a web based one. How would I use res and req in this case?

Comment: Nevermind, just changing the schema to your suggestion worked! I want to understand how that worked, though. Could you explain it to me?